# Errors while calling a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a time and date clock. I am getting all sorts of errors when trying to call a function:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Very Simple Clock By Ashton</title>
    <script>

        console.log("beginning creation of update function");

        function update() {
            document.getElementById('timeOutput').innerHTML = Date();
        }

        console.log("Successfully created update function");

        console.log("Calling the update function")

        update();

        console.log("successfully called the update function");
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p onload="update()" id="timeOutput">ERROR | Could Not Retrieve Time from server</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I figured out that it is because of the fact i ran the script before the p tag was even created. thanks to everybody for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Body,Img,Iframe tags only have `onload` event `p` not supported.So Change with `onclick` event instead of `onload`

Only onload of `p`

```js
console.log("beginning creation of update function");

        function update() {
            document.getElementById('timeOutput').innerHTML = Date();
        }
```

```html
<p onload="update()" id="timeOutput">ERROR | Could Not Retrieve Time from server</p>
```

**Change** to click

```js
console.log("beginning creation of update function");

        function update() {
            document.getElementById('timeOutput').innerHTML = Date();
        }

        console.log("Successfully created update function");

        console.log("Calling the update function")

        update();

        console.log("successfully called the update function");
```

```html
<p onclick="update()" id="timeOutput">ERROR | Could Not Retrieve Time from server</p>
```

Comment: No its working only dom calling `update()` in your script tag.Not with onload of p

Answer (score 0):

Onload does not work for `<p>` tags, so it is useless.

Enclosing `update()` inside `window.onload()` would allow it to work.